# Get top 5 values where key total is less than or equal to X

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I have a list of items someone can buy as follows:

```
my_list = [
    ('Candy', 1.0, 20.5),
    ('Soda', 3.0, 10.25),
    ('Coffee', 1.2, 20.335),
    ('Soap', 1.2, 11.5),
    ('Spoon', 0.2, 2.32),
    ('Toast', 3.2, 12.335),
    ('Toothpaste', 3, 20.5),
    ('Creamer', .1, 5.5),
    ('Sugar', 2.2, 5.2),
]
```

Each item is set up like this:

```
('Item Name', ItemCost, ItemValue)
```

I have the list pulling the items with the top 5 `ItemValue`.

```
print nlargest(5, my_list, key=itemgetter(2))
>>> [
        ('Candy', 1.0, 20.5),
        ('Toothpaste', 3, 20.5),
        ('Coffee', 1.2, 20.335),
        ('Toast', 3.2, 12.335),
        ('Soap', 1.2, 11.5),
    ]
```

I am trying to retrieve a result where I get the top 5 total `ItemValue` where the top 5 total `ItemCost` is equal or less than 6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just add a filter stage before you call `nlargest`.

Comment: I answered the question but now reading the post again I think I maybe get it wrong. When do you say "the top 5 total ItemCost" with total you mean it sum?

Comment: @PaulRooney if you read the `total item cost` must be equal to or less than 6, simply filtering wont account for that, you need to have a combination of 5 that has a total less than or equal to `6`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede the question isn't very clear. `where the top 5 total ItemCost is equal or less than 6.` doesnt make sense to me anyway.

Comment: @PaulRooney you have to compile a top 5 list, where the the item cost of the 5 combined is equal to or less than 6

Comment: @PaulRooney so say you pull a top 5 and two of those items are soda and toast you are already at a total of 6 that would not work

Comment: The op could clarify his question by providing a sample output.

Comment: Rafeal already got it

Comment: He was getting there!To be a bit more descriptive, and to reflect what I said in my comment to the answer below;  Essentially, it would just pull the largest possible total ItemValue but the total cost of the 5 items has to be <= 6.

Comment: can you add desired output too and how large your list can be ?

Comment: @Tanmayjain i think OP means the list _has to consists of 5 top values items_ & their total costs are _closest to 6 if not equal_ to 6 _compared_ to other possible combinations

Comment: @cryptonome OP wants list that consists of 5 items( tuples) such that these 5 items have highest value but if the total cost ( ie sum of item cost of this 5 items) exceeds 6 then remove lowest value item from the list and pick another such that total cost remain under 6 or equal to 6 you will need to keep doing this until you find right combination.

Comment: that is what i was saying??

Comment: `For given sample data:
answer  TotalValue TotalCost  TotalValue/ TotalCost
RafaelC 60.155     3.7        16.258
others    69.155     5.5        12.573`

Comment: @cryptonome you must have edited the comment because at first I didn't read this also I lost internet connection.. so maybe I was seeing the old comment.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is in the class of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), in this case a multiple objective knapsack problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can filter first, and use all following `nlargest` on your filtered list.

```
f = [(a,b,c) for (a,b,c) in my_list if b <= 6]
```

But for data manipulation like this, `pandas` can be very useful. Take, for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=('ItemName', 'ItemCost', 'ItemValue'))

    ItemName    ItemCost    ItemValue
0   Candy       1.0         20.500
1   Soda        3.0         10.250
2   Coffee      1.2         20.335
3   Soap        1.2         11.500
4   Spoon       0.2         2.320
5   Toast       3.2         12.335
6   Toothpaste  3.0         20.500
7   Creamer     0.1         5.500
8   Sugar       2.2         5.200

>>> df[df.ItemCost <= 6]

    ItemName    ItemCost    ItemValue
0   Candy       1.0         20.500
1   Soda        3.0         10.250
2   Coffee      1.2         20.335
3   Soap        1.2         11.500
4   Spoon       0.2         2.320
5   Toast       3.2         12.335
6   Toothpaste  3.0         20.500
7   Creamer     0.1         5.500
8   Sugar       2.2         5.200

>>> df[df.ItemCost <= 6].nlargest(n=5, columns=['ItemValue'])


    ItemName    ItemCost    ItemValue
0   Candy       1.0         20.500
6   Toothpaste  3.0         20.500
2   Coffee      1.2         20.335
5   Toast       3.2         12.335
3   Soap        1.2         11.500
```

---

If you want, you can first get the `nsmallest` of the `ItemCost` and *just then* get the `nlargest`

```
df.nsmallest(n=5, columns=['ItemCost']).nlargest(n=5, columns=['ItemValue'])    

    ItemName    ItemCost    ItemValue
0   Candy       1.0         20.500
2   Coffee      1.2         20.335
3   Soap        1.2         11.500
7   Creamer     0.1         5.500
4   Spoon       0.2         2.320
```

Comment: This doesn't  meet all conditions if I understand correctly, the top 5 `total item cost <= 6`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Not sure what you or OP mean by that. What would be the expected output ?

Comment: I'm assuming that the top 5 items item cost combined must be equal to or less than 6

Comment: your total item cost would be 9.4

Comment: and then he would want a total item value from those 5 items

Comment: Well then get the `nsmallest` and then `nlargest`.

Comment: How does the updated answer incorporate the less than or equal to 6 requirement?

Comment: @PaulRooney look at his first list, total the item cost column, it equals 9.4, look at the new list, the total is less than 6

Comment: @PaulRooney Well Paul, if the `nsmallest` summed are still greater than `6`, then there is no solution for the problem. If there are other solutions beyond those of the `nsmallest`, then I assumed they do not matter since the total cost is not the optimal one (they will be greater than or equal the `nsmallest` solution)

Comment: @RafaelC the only thing I wonder is if we substitute `soda` for `toothpaste` we would still be under `6` with a greater total item value, OP would have to confirm if this is desired

Comment: @vash_the_stampede correct, toothpaste would have more ItemValue.

Essentially, it would just pull the largest possible total ItemValue but the total cost of the 5 items has to be <= 6

Thank you guys very much for helping me out here!

Comment: @ DarkMatter so higher the total ItemValue better it will be, only restriction is that Total cost should not exceed 6. `For given sample data: answer TotalValue TotalCost TotalValue/ TotalCost RafaelC 60.155 3.7 16.258 others 69.155 5.5 12.573` which means other answers gives your desired result but almost all of us are using combination for it. I hope your list size is small else it will take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you asking,

I would first create all possible combinations of 5 elements from my_list

```
itertools.combinations(my_list, 5)
```

Then i would find all possible combinations in result where total item cost would be less than or equal to 6.

```
f = [element for element in itertools.combinations(my_list, 5) if  sum([e[1] for e in element]) <=6]
```

Now, I would find that element where total itemValue is the greatest

```
h = [sum([g[2] for g in e]) for e in f]
```

The index of element with maximum itemValue is

```
index = h.index(max(h))
```

Now, you can find that element in f.

```
f[index]
```

The answer i got is

```
 Candy        1.0  20.5
 Coffee       1.2  20.335
 Spoon        0.2  2.32
 Toothpaste   3    20.5
 Creamer      0.1  5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import combinations
from beautifultable import BeautifulTable

def pretty_print( lst):
    table = BeautifulTable()
    table.column_headers = ['Item Name','ItemCost','ItemValue']
    if lst:
        for item_specs in lst:
            table.append_row(item_specs)
        print(table)


def get_total_cost( lst):
    return sum(item_specs[1] for item_specs in lst)

def get_total_Value( lst):
    return sum(item_specs[2] for item_specs in lst)



def best_comb( item_list, number_of_items_to_pick, cost_constraint):


    k = number_of_items_to_pick

    item_list.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True) # sorting list by ItemValue

    k_top_value_item_lst = item_list[:5] # picking top k items from list

    total_cost = get_total_cost(k_top_value_item_lst)


    def generateCombinations( take_default_val_for_best_result = True):
        k_len_combination_list = list(combinations( item_list, k))

        if take_default_val_for_best_result:
            best_result = []# which meets total itemCost <= 6 condition and have highest total of ItemValue 
            best_result_sum = [0,0] # ItemCost, ItemValue    
        else:
            best_result = k_top_value_item_lst
            best_result_sum = [total_cost, get_total_Value(best_result)]


        best_alternative_lst = [] # if there are any other combination which offer same Value for Cost

        # ignore first comb as its been already suggested to user
        for comb in k_len_combination_list:

            temp_sum = [None,None]
            temp_sum[0] = get_total_cost( comb)
            reset_best = False

            if  temp_sum[0] <= cost_constraint:
                temp_sum[1] = get_total_Value( comb)

                if best_result_sum[1] < temp_sum[1]:
                    reset_best = True

                elif best_result_sum[1] == temp_sum[1]:
                    if temp_sum[0] < best_result_sum[0]:
                        reset_best = True
                    elif temp_sum[0] == best_result_sum[0]:
                        # since ItemValue as well as ItemCost are equivalent to best_result this comb is great alternative
                        if comb != tuple(best_result):
                            best_alternative_lst.append(comb)

                if reset_best:
                    best_result = comb
                    best_result_sum[1] = temp_sum[1]
                    best_result_sum[0] = temp_sum[0]

        print('Best Combination:')
        if best_result:
            pretty_print(best_result)
        else:
            print('not found')

        if gen_alternative:
            print('\nBest Alternative Combination:')
            if best_alternative_lst:
                for idx,alter_comb in enumerate( best_alternative_lst):
                    comb_id = idx+1
                    print('combination_id ',comb_id)
                    pretty_print(alter_comb)
            else:
                print('not found')


    if total_cost > cost_constraint:
        generateCombinations()

    else:
        if gen_alternative:
            generateCombinations(take_default_val_for_best_result = False)

        else:
            print('Best Combination:')
            pretty_print(k_top_value_item_lst)



my_list = [
    ('Candy', 2.0, 20.5),
    ('Soda', 1.5, 25.7 ), 
    ('Coffee', 2.4, 25.7 ),
    ('Soap', 1.2,20),
    ('Spoon',1.2,20 ), 
    ('Toast',1.2,22 ),
    ('Toothpaste',0.8, 20 ), 
    ('Creamer',0.8, 22),
    ('Sugar',2.0, 20.5 ),
]

gen_alternative = input('do you want to generate alternative combinations: y/n ')[0].lower() == 'y'

best_comb( my_list, 5, 6)
```

Answer to modified list ( to show extra feature)

```
do you want to generate alternative combinations: y/n Y
Best Combination:
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Item Name  | ItemCost | ItemValue |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|    Soda    |   1.5    |   25.7    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   Toast    |   1.2    |    22     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|  Creamer   |   0.8    |    22     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|    Soap    |   1.2    |    20     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Toothpaste |   0.8    |    20     |
+------------+----------+-----------+

Best Alternative Combination:
combination_id  1
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Item Name  | ItemCost | ItemValue |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|    Soda    |   1.5    |   25.7    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   Toast    |   1.2    |    22     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|  Creamer   |   0.8    |    22     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   Spoon    |   1.2    |    20     | <---
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Toothpaste |   0.8    |    20     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer to your original list

```
Best Combination:
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Item Name  | ItemCost | ItemValue |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   Candy    |   1.0    |   20.5    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Toothpaste |    3     |   20.5    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   Coffee   |   1.2    |  20.335   |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|  Creamer   |   0.1    |    5.5    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   Spoon    |   0.2    |   2.32    |
+------------+----------+-----------+

Best Alternative Combination:
not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure of what you are trying to do, but...
If you are trying to retrieve the top x (5 or 6) based on `itemcost` sorted by lowest cost, you can try this.

```
x=5
sorted(my_list, key=lambda s : s[2])[:x]

This outputs the following:

[('Spoon', 0.2, 2.32),
('Sugar', 2.2, 5.2),
('Creamer', 0.1, 5.5),
('Soda', 3.0, 10.25),
('Soap', 1.2, 11.5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

def get_valid_combs(lis):
    "find all combinations that cost less than or equal to 6"

    for i in combinations(lis, 5):
        if reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + x[1], list(i), 0) <= 6:
            yield list(i)

my_list = [
    ('Candy', 1.0, 20.5),
    ('Soda', 3.0, 10.25),
    ('Coffee', 1.2, 20.335),
    ('Soap', 1.2, 11.5),
    ('Spoon', 0.2, 2.32),
    ('Toast', 3.2, 12.335),
    ('Toothpaste', 3, 20.5),
    ('Creamer', .1, 5.5),
    ('Sugar', 2.2, 5.2),
]

# find all valid combinations which  cost less than 6
valid_combinations = [i for i in get_valid_combs(my_list)]

#top_combinations_sorted = sorted(valid_combinations, key=lambda y: reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + x[2], [0]+y))

# of the valid combinations get the combination with highest total value
best_combination = max(valid_combinations, key=lambda y: reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + x[2], y, 0))

print(best_combination)
```

output:

```
[('Candy', 1.0, 20.5), ('Coffee', 1.2, 20.335), ('Spoon', 0.2, 2.32), ('Toothpaste', 3, 20.5), ('Creamer', 0.1, 5.5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations

...

total_cost = lambda item: int(sum(c for _, c, _ in item) <= 6) * sum(v for _, _ , v in item)
chosen = max(combinations(my_list, 5), key=total_cost)
```

Max can receive a function to specify max criteria.

The total_cost function, has a int(sum(c for _, c, _ in item) <= 6) portion that is 1 if total cost of the combination is less or equal then 6, and its 0 otherwise.

We then multiply this portion with the total sum of values.

combinations(my_list, 5) retrieves all possible combinations of my_list items having 5 items.

Printing chosen elements you have:

```
('Candy', 1.0, 20.5)
('Coffee', 1.2, 20.335)
('Spoon', 0.2, 2.32)
('Toothpaste', 3, 20.5)
('Creamer', 0.1, 5.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list first:

`print nlargest(5, [item for item in my_list if item[1]<=6], key=itemgetter(2))`

You can do it with sorted too:

`sorted([item for item in my_list if item[1]<=6], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:5]`

The above filters out items with *ItemCost* greater than 6, sorts your list descending based on *ItemCost*, and then returns the first 5 element

Answer (score 0):

First using `combinations` we can get all possible combinations of 5 from `my_list`. From here we can use `filter` and only return combinations whose total `ItemCost` is less than or equal to `6`.  Finally we sort by the which group has the highest total `ItemValue` and we take the greatest one being `l2[-1]` we could use `reverse = True` and then it would be `l2[0]`

from itertools import combinations

```
l = list(combinations(my_list, 5))
l1 = list(filter(lambda x: sum([i[1] for i in x]) < 6, l))
l2 = sorted(l1, key=lambda x: sum([i[2] for i in x]))
print(l2[-1])
```

> ```
> (('Candy', 1.0, 20.5), ('Coffee', 1.2, 20.335), ('Spoon', 0.2, 2.32), ('Toothpaste', 3, 20.5), ('Creamer', 0.1, 5.5))
> ```